# Vimeo OAuth2 API return empty result for /me/videos

Tags: php, api, video, vimeo

I'm using old Vimeo API, and I'd like to move on new OAuth2 API.

But I can't figure how to get my videos list, using **/me/videos** entry point.
API always returns me an empty result:

```
array (size=3)
'body' => null
'status' => int 0
'headers' => array (size=0) empty
```

I'm using new Vimeo PHP SDK (https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php) like this way:

```
<?php

$vimeo = new Vimeo($clientId, $clientSecret);
$response = $vimeo->clientCredentials();
$vimeo->setToken($response);
die(var_dump($vimeo->request('/me/videos')));
```

Of course I have a video test in my account, in public mode.
Any idea to get out of this behavior?

Many thanks for your help,
Philippe

Answer (score 0):

the php api you wanted to use is not for oauth2 integration. You should check related instructions on vimeo's developer site.